# pass any object to function to create this object

Tags: c++, oop, openframeworks

I'm making a small generative video layering software using openframeworks and c++. To this effect I have one main class, one layer class and a lot of different types of video/simulations class. I need to make it so that when I press a key, a different simulation is loaded.

I have two questions :

1. How can I access a list of all my simulation classes ?
2. Following up, how can I feed one choice from this list into a function that can take any type of object and initiate it ?

I made a drawing instead of using to code brackets to have all 3 blocks on the same horizontal level (actual code is underneath).

[image]

Here's the main.cpp and the layer.cpp in code for clarity :

```
// main.cpp
void ofApp::setup(){
    layer1.setup();
    layer2.setup();
    layer3.setup();
}

void ofApp::update(){
    layer1.update(); 
    layer2.update(); 
    layer3.update(); 
}

void ofApp::draw(){
    layer1.draw(); 
    layer2.draw(); 
    layer3.draw(); 
}

void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){
    switch (key)
    {
    case '1':
        // get first class from list of classes
        layer1.changeSim(); // input first class from list of simulation classes
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and the layer.cpp

```
void layer::setup(){
simulation = new Simulation();  // how do i initialize the Simulation variable if I dont know what type itll be ?
}

void layer::update(){
    simulation.update(); 
}

void layer::draw(){
    simulation.draw(); 
}

void layer::changeSim(){
    simulation = new Simulation(); // destroy old simulation and create new one, but will be of a different class
}
```

Comment: This sounds like good fit for the [factory pattern](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/02/factory-selfregister.html): you register a constructor for every simulation class that takes a generic parameters object. You can then look up the constructor by name and invoke it to get back instantiated Simulation object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method to do this is to use something called the factory pattern.

Basically, define a function that takes an argument of some defined type that can be used to figure out what kind of simulation you want, and then create that simulation and return a pointer to it.

A simple version of it might look like this:

```
enum SimulationType
{
    Simulation_None,
    Simulation_Basic,
    Simulation_Complex,
...
};

Simulation* CreateSimulation(SimulationType Type)
{
    switch(Type)
    {
    case Simulation_None:
    default:
        return nullptr;
    case Simulation_Basic:
        return new BasicSimulation();
    case Simulation_Complex:
        return new ComplexSimulation();
...
    }
}

...

void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){
    switch (key)
    {
    case '1':
        // get first class from list of classes
        layer1.changeSim(Simulation_Basic); // input first class from list of simulation classes
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

...

void layer::setup(){
simulation = CreateSimulation(Simulation_None);
}

void layer::changeSim(SimulationType Type){
    if(simulation) delete simulation;
    simulation = CreateSimulation(Type);
}
```

This is a simple example - you could also use a table indexed by `SimulationType`, an ordered map of `SimulationType` that references static constructor functions for each type, basically anything that associates an identifier with a constructor function.

Comment: thank you so much for the fast answer ! currently reading into all this so thanks ! :)
there's one thing I'm having a little trouble understanding though. So I am creating a function like you mentioned which is Simulation* CreateSimulation(SimulationType Type) inside my layer class.
I get that the input comes from the enum, but the output type being Simulation* is udnefined, and so is the "simulation" variable inside layer::setup() and layer::changeSim is uninitialized, how do I define a type for these as there are many possible Simulation classes

Comment: O i get it, I declared them as `static Layer *CreateSimulation(SimulationType Type);` and `Layer* simulation;`

Comment: Whatever your base class is for the various simulations is the type you want to use. That way you can inherit from it to customize your behavior.

Comment: Wait this doesn't make sense to me, why would the return of CreateSimulation would be of type Layer when we want it to be of the type of the simulation to be able to interact with it ? I've succesfully implemented everything you developped on, but my return object is of type Layer and creates a stack overflow when I call simulation.setup() inside the layer.cpp setup() function

Comment: Does `simulation` in `Layer` represent the simulation used for that particular layer, or does it represent the layer underneath the current layer?

Comment: I read about polymorphism and I think I got it :) thanks a lot for the help !